# A strange issue when SubViewController add to its ParentViewController at the first time

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define NAVIGATIONBARHEIGHT 64.0
#define TABBARHEIGHT 49.0

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *viewController = [self viewControllerIndex:0];
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);//**strange issue is here**
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

When the first time the SubViewController is added,I think the it's frame height should be "SCREEN_HEIGHT - NAVIGATIONBARHEIGHT - TABBARHEIGHT", but it's not, it looks like :

[image]

But I changed the SubViewController's frame height to "SCREEN_HEIGHT" is OK, it's looks like:

[image]

I am very confused, why "SCREEN_HEIGHT" is OK?

Comment: Are you defining your `SCREEN_HEIGHT ` like this? `#define SCREEN_HEIGHT  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height`

Comment: @Abhinav Sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your view as subview to navigation controller's view and your navigation controller seems to be embedded into tab bar controller. Technically, your subviews will be clipped off and cannot overlap navigation controller' nav bar and tab bar controller' tab bar. This is how these controllers are designed. What you are expecting is basically doable with a custom nav bar and tab bar.